# Data stream handlers and CLI incorporation Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, node-commander

I am trying to create an interactive CLI that can run serial commands. I have two files serialcomms.js and cli.js. Serialcomms.js contains the connection, handlers, and command functions. cli.js contains the commander information.

My issue is that I can only call the send command once because the listeners/handlers take over from the serialcomms file. What would be the best method to loop the cli program so I can call the send command over and over again, but still have the serial handlers running and output to stdout? Would I need to use a child process? Or recursion to have the cli call itself?

Example behavior I am expecting with an echo bot on the other end of the serial line.

- Send hello
- hello
- Send Bye
- Bye

Behavior I am experiencing

- Send hello
- hello
- **endless wait**

Here is my serialcomms.js

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ReadLine = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

let portName = `/dev/pts/${process.argv[2]}` || '/dev/pts/6';
let baudRate = process.argv[3] || 115200;


let myPort = new SerialPort(portName, {baudRate: baudRate})
let parser = myPort.pipe(new ReadLine({ delimiter: '\n' }))

myPort.on('open', () => {
    console.log(`port ${portName} open`)
  })

  parser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })

  myPort.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`port ${portName} closed`)
  })

  myPort.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('port error: ' + err)
  })



function send(data){
    myPort.write(JSON.stringify(data)+'\n', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
        }
        console.log(`${data} sent`);
      });
}

module.exports = {
    send
}
```

Here is my CLI.js file

```
const program = require('commander');
const {send} = require('./serialcomms');

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .description('Serial Tester')

program
    .command('send <msg>')
    .alias('s')
    .description('send a message over serial')
    .action((msg)=>{
        send(msg)
    })

program.parse(process.argv)
```